# How to know if process is application - Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, taskmanager

Using [EnumProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I am able to get list of currently running processes. But how do I know which of them are applications?  I am talking this w.r.t. task manager, see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/209654/whats-the-difference-between-an-application-process-and-services).

I guess `IsWindow()` function is what I need.. right? If not, please guide further.

Comment: How do you define "application"?

Comment: see the link posted in the w.r.t... or rather something that is visible to user, which has window to work on..

Comment: Why do you want to know in the first place?

Comment: I would want to do something with the window that is being displayed.. and with all of them

Comment: -1. This question not make sense for me.

Comment: @user2120666 I appreciate that you atleast told the reason. Its a good habit to tell..

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the top-level visible windows. Find these with `EnumWindows`. This enumerates all top-level windows. The ones you are interested are the visible ones. Call `IsWindowVisible` to obtain that information.

Comment: +1 for a simple, logical answer, and because I ain't afraid of no ghost.

Comment: no no.. I considered this option of `EnumWindows` but i was not able to get how many windows are there. This i get using `EnumProcesses`. I have something to do with all the visible windows and for that I need how many of those are there. Can you tell how to get this number using `EnumWindows()`?

Comment: Why do you need to know that? Just add any qualifying windows into a list and that's it.

Comment: Also, the question starts by stating that you are using EnumWindows.

Comment: no no sir, I am using `EnumProcesses` . what i am doing is dependent on how many windows are visible. Its business policy that I can not tell you what exactly me doing or my boss kills me

Comment: If you decide that it's not possible to use EnumWindows because it won't tell you how many windows there are before you call it, then you have to give up and tell your boss that the task is impossible. Will he kill you in that scenario too?!